# "Error when checking funcall(doc, parameter-ref ...)" only after building Java 8 system

Tags: java, xml, xslt, intellij-idea

I have a Java 8 system that performs a series of XSLT transformations. It works perfectly fine.

However, once I build the system, during one of the transformations I get the error code: `Error when checking funcall(doc, [parameter-ref(Param_1/reference)])`.

My XSLT receives a file path as a parameter, and I prepare it using the following snippet:

```
private LinkedList<String[]> getParamsList(String fileName, int max, String paramName,
                                           String lastPName, String lastPPath) {
    // Prepare the uri
    String uri = fileName.replace(File.separator, "/");

    // Create a list
    LinkedList<String[]> parameters = new LinkedList<>();

    // Add basic parameters
    for(int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
        // Create the element
        String[] param = {paramName + i, "file:/" + uri};
        parameters.add(param);
    }

    // Create the last one
    String[] lastParam = {lastPName,
            (new File(lastPPath)).getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separator, "/")
    };
    parameters.addLast(lastParam);

    // Return the list
    return parameters;
}
```

And then use it during the transformation, with:

```
private void transform(String xslt, LinkedList<String[]> params, File startFile, File endFile)
        throws TransformerException {
    // Prepare the factory and source
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(new File(xslt));

    // Prepare the transformation
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
    for(String[] p: params) {
        transformer.setParameter(p[0], p[1]);
    }

    // Obtain the input file
    Source text = new StreamSource(startFile);
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(endFile));
}
```

The XSLT has the following section:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_1" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_2" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_3" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_4" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_5" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_6" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_7" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="Param_8" select="''"/>
```

The "file path" I'm sending is the `.getAbsolutePath()` return.

However, I don't understand why this is not working. It works perfectly when run from the IDE (IntelliJ), but it throws that error after built. What I have checked:

- Correctly finding the XSLT file.
- The file path of `fileName` is correct, and the file *does* exist.
- Previous transformations work perfectly!
- Tried to remove the `"file:/"`concatenation and again: works on the IDE, it does not work when built. Tried to use `.getCanonicalPath()` with the same result.

Comment: So where/how else does the XSLT use `Param_1`?

Comment: Any chance that inside of the IDE you have Saxon 9 on the class path but with the built application not and the stylesheet is an XSLT  2.0 one using the `doc` function not supported by XSLT 1.0 and Xalan of the JRE?

Comment: Martin Honnen strangely, it was added to the artifact. I removed it, added it again, and it is now working perfectly. Thank you very much! You should put this as an answer, though, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we found out in the exchange in the comments, the error message occurred as you tried to use XSLT 2.0 and the XSLT/XPath 2.0 `doc` function which requires an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 but somehow in your final app setup Saxon 9 was not on the classpath and that way the built-in XSLT 1.0 processor Xalan in the JRE tried to execute the stylesheet and gave you that error message as it does not know the `doc` function.

To fix that you had to ensure that Saxon 9 is on the classpath both in your IDE as well as with the built application.